# How to get all files and directories by user in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying to find all the directories and files owned by user with the following command.

```
find / -type d -user greg | grep -v proc
```

it is working fine sometimes and hanging up sometimes. Is there any performance issues associated with it or is there any better way to executing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it from descending into `/proc`, use `-prune`. It's better than filtering out entries with `grep -v` as it'll avoid descending into `/proc` at all.

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o -type d -user greg -print
```

Read `-o` as "or". If the path is `/proc`, prune it, i.e. don't go in there. Otherwise, match directories owned by greg. (If you want files too then get rid of the `-type d` test.)

When you use `-prune`, you also have to use `-print` to print matches. `-print`'s normally implied, but using `-prune` changes that.